# How to crack RSA Encryption when the n has many factors?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We need to crack this encryption.

$n = 9952557691515537655603704364099493361893723995530560442152723450122354291175996449486024618905908426527010155976171498128383190834634939607277311797262931251606228507159901357$

$e = 2333709022697429575794394667688643654259674326306594071851895621000004047771513595219241165780701413122685522219258899488672486350676041801010142735336468799546002450282578559$

We got told to study the n.

By factoring n, I got a bunch of factors.

$(797569*(276901*(436181*(569573*(315269*(963629*(775267*(285343*(429413*(517547*(399221*(640631*(150169*389531*518767)*551059*414383^3)*948293)*970903)*397429)*229777)*416089)*711691)*254899)*280879)*814309)*367841)*476737)*156781$

Next step for us is to decrypt to message.

$7352103118079246975555121483640196351329662419499716040211703425109093716002765938641251337191107581585817422028452319168290493113804360780681839472544286478396163719825606037$

$5090894178034957948515656781392285210239986446522114347510620962973247373506266501186832946853414844164531669372519027977978562727270659020897736863718711864392712264330659886$

By looking to decrypt code, we need to find the value of d, which is $e^-1 mod(p-1)(q-1)$, which would be easy if we were to find a single p and q, but instead, I received all those factors. What's the way to work around that issue? I've tried some combinations of p and q, but to no effort.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Why the parentheses?

Comment: That's what Maple got me out, and I was too lazy to change that, sorry.

Comment: How are we to interpret the decrypted message?

Comment: It's the password of an excel file.

Answer (score 2):

For decrypting an RSA message,
you choose $d$ where $ 0 < d < \phi(n)$ and $e \cdot d \equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(n)}$. So, $d$ is the modular inverse of $e$ under $\phi(n)$.

Here, $\phi(n)$ is the euler phi function given by,
$$ \phi(n) = n \prod_{p\,\mid\,n} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right)$$
Notice that if $n = pq$ where $p,q$ are prime, then $\phi(n) = (p-1)(q-1)$.

So in this problem, you cannot use $(p-1)(q-1)$ and would need to use the above general formula to find $\phi(n)$.
Then, decrypt the message using $m \equiv c^d \pmod n$.